# Getting page/category content to show up in my custom page template

Tags: categories, customization, pages, templates

I am trying to get my category page content to show up in my custom page template, it returns everything I call, except for the actual page content when I am testing it. Hope this is somewhat clear :\ I've tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to get the job done so I have no real example code.

Thanks in advance :-))

Comment: Without seeing any code it is difficult to say what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need to show a specific category index on a page template, right?

If that's the case you can use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Page Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- If you want to retrieve the page title, content, ... -->
    <?php the_post(); // set up the post ?>
    <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
    <div class="content"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div>

    <!-- Then your category index -->
    <?php
    $category_id = get_cat_ID('YOUR CATEGORY NAME');
    $args = array(
        'cat'   => $category_id,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
    );
    $cat_posts = new WP_query( $args );
    if($cat_posts->have_posts()):
        while($cat_posts->have_posts()):
            $cat_posts->the_post();
    ?>

        <div class="cat_post">
            <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
            <div class="content"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="pagination">
            <?php next_posts_link( __('Older Entries'), $cat_posts->max_num_pages ); ?>
            <?php previous_posts_link( __('Next Entries') ); ?>
        </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Remember to change `YOUR CATEGORY NAME` accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply :D That indeed should do the job, and it did. I had already fixed it, there was a minor mistake in my code and after staring at it for too long I was no longer able to recognize it.